# Find median of a set of Data in matlab then find Average of that data

Tags: matlab, matrix, mode, mean

I am trying to take an input such as:

```
StarT:
2141865 16
2141865 17
2141865 17
2141865 16
2141865 17
2141865 20
2141865 9
2141865 7
2141865 19
2141865 18
2141865 19
2141865 9
2141865 9
2141865 9
2141865 9
2301367 11
2301367 21
2301367 12
2301367 10
2301367 10
2301367 11
2301367 10
2301367 10
2301367 19
2301367 12
2301367 19
2301367 10
2301367 10
2301367 18
2301367 23
2308980 16
2308980 17
```

into matlab and find the median of the second column with respect to the first column as an index(matching data sets). I also need to then take the mean of that set of data with certain conditions, such as if the original value is within a certain rang (1.5* larger or smaller) then it must adjust the original value to be either 1.5* bigger or smaller (depending on the difference between it and the mode). I have tried the following code and it is giving me close results but not exactly what I need:
(I do not have the below code setup for calculating the averages as I cannot figure out how to go about that until the mode is correct)

```
function Mode_Koi_2

StarData = evalin('base', 'StarP');

global medians;

[medians, ~, Groups] = unique(StarData(:,1),'stable');
medians = [medians, accumarray(Groups, StarData(:,2), [], @median)];


end
```

Now all I need is a loop or accumarray function to compare the median values in 'medians' with the original values for the corresponding ID in 'StarP', and subsequently adjust them if there is the need to (if the value of the original data is smaller or larger as stated above), then find the average of StarP.

Comment: Why not use the built-in `mode` frunction:http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html ? Also why the global variables?

Comment: Well I do use mode in  the accumarray but I need to use accumarray because of the values of the first column being repeated and not always consistent by which I mean that there are 5 instances of all of the values in the example to simplify it but in reality there can be between 4-10 instances of each repeated index

Comment: I don't fully follow your question or how you calculate your modes. Surely this finds the modes: `S = sortrows(StarData);
                              accumarray(S(:,1), S(:,2), [], @mode)`
as in surely the corresponding mode of col 2 for a `1` is col 1 is also `1` (based on your examples data) and coincidentally the same thing for `2` and `3`?

Comment: It does, however I realized I never posted the output so I will update that now

Comment: Can you explain your output - because my code disagrees. The mode of data in column 2 for rows corresponding to rows of column 1 containing the number `2` is also 2 for your data. But your output makes it look like it's `1`?

Comment: Yea that's why I'm confused, I thought it should be in order as well, but column 1 does not seem matched with column 2 and I don't know why.

Comment: Your code also prints out an equally large array as the input and I need an array with just one row containing the mode of all of the data points with a corresponding index

Comment: No my code returns [1;2;3]

Comment: In fact you can just do this: `accumarray(StarData(:,1), StarData(:,2), [], @mode)` and still get the right answer. (This will be in order of appearance for each group in col1). Oh and also I'm assuming your `StarData` and your `StarT` are the same thing?

Comment: Well yes, StarData and StarT are similar in format but not in actual values, I'm using starT to run tests and if you could type up a sample of the code youre using cleanly in an answer then maybe I can test it out and go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[medians, ~, Groups] = unique(StarT(:,1),'stable');
medians = [medians, accumarray(Groups, StarT(:,2), [], @median)]
```

results in

```
medians =

     2141865           9
     2301367          10
     2308980          16
```

Comment: I need to be able to keep the index value from my original list that corresponds to the mode that we find

Comment: @ImmortalxR use `unique` with the `'stable'` flag as in my edit

Comment: okay that seems better, but when I try that with my other code I still get problems with the indexes, ill update the OP to show you what I mean.

Comment: @ImmortalxR Updated, please make the examples in your question match the data you provide.

Comment: That's fantastic, the new code works perfectly; I am working on implementing my own loop to find the averages now as stated in the OP but if you would like to add that to your answer I would like to compare and I'll gladly upvote this answer.

Comment: @ImmortalxR I did not understand your question regarding the averages, I suggest you ask it as a new question and define it more clearly

Comment: @ImmortalxR Also you must drop the `global` and `evalin`. Rather do this: `function medians = Mode_Koi_2(StarData)`

Comment: Okay I removed the global, would you mind if I sent you a link to the new question once I post it?

Comment: @ImmortalxR Not at all. Please try include a work example with data though, you can do it by hand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498341/comparing-two-matrices-in-matalb-with-different-array-sizes Thats the link for the new question, thanks.