# Comparing two matrices in MATLAB with different array sizes

Tags: arrays, matlab

So here is my sample Data:

```
Arr StarP:
2141865 16
2141865 17
2141865 17
2141865 16
2141865 17
2141865 20
2141865 9
2141865 7
2141865 19
2141865 18
2141865 19
2141865 9
2141865 9
2141865 9
2141865 9
Arr medians:
2141865 16
```

The goal is to compare Arr StarP to Arr medians and find if any value with a corresponding ID (2141865) in Arr StarP is within a certain range of the value for that ID in Arr medians (if it is 1.5* larger or 1.5* smaller), and if it is not then it needs to be multiplied or divided by 1.5. If the value of Arr StarP is 2* larger or smaller than Arr medians then I want that value ignored in the new average calculation.

Example Output:

```
2141865 14.00666667
```

P.S. The real size of Arr B is 198x2 and Arr A is 45879x2, Arr A has many many different ID's in it and Arr B has exactly 198, Arr B was derived from finding the medians of all of the values in Arr A with a matching ID and outputting that median along with the ID.

Comment: I have tried using accumarray and ismember but as I am not so used to matlab I don't understand what way to approach this, I also tried for loops with nested if statements but that doesn't match the indexes correctly because of the format of the files.

Comment: Please, provide a copy-pastable example, also where `B` makes sense.

Comment: The edit shows all I have so far and how medians is derived from StarP, the ismember was my attempt to start a loop but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @ImmortalxR Please add an ArrB as well and a handworked example output

Comment: @Dan I dont quite understand what more you want for Arr B (medians), that is exactly what it looks like. I also just added example output.

Comment: So..I'm not getting why I was downvoted on this? Any hints maybe?

Comment: @ImmortalxR why is your example output only one row? Surely it should be as long as Arr A?

Comment: @Dan The code I show takes all of the values from A(:,2) with matching A(:,1) and just prints a single row output with A(i,1) and @median(A(i,2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [medians, newAverage] = Medians_Koi(StarData, R, M)

    %//R is this range outside of which values must be multiplied. I'm assuming it's expressed in terms of the median, so for example if R is [0.8, 1.2] and the median is 10 then the range allowed is 8 - 12.
    %//M is what to multiply by (this really should have been explained in the question)

    %//why are you doing this with global and evalin?? This is really really bad practice and there is no reason for it. Just make the function accept input arguments and output output arguments
    %//StarData = evalin('base', 'StarP');
    %//global medians;
    %//global newAvg;

    StarData2 = StarData;

    [IDs, ~, Groups_1] = unique(StarData(:,1),'stable');
    medians = [IDs, accumarray(Groups_1, StarData(:,2), [], @median)];

    for g = 1:size(Group_1,1)
        toMultiply = (StarData(:,1)==IDs(g)) & (StarData(:,2) < medians(g)*R(1));
        toDivide = (StarData(:,1)==IDs(g)) & (StarData(:,2) > medians(g)*R(2));
        StarData2(toMultiply,2) = StarData(toMultiply,2) .* M(1);
        StarData2(toDivide,2) = StarData(toDivide,2) ./ M(2);
    end

    newAverage = [IDs, accumarray(Groups_1, StarData2(:,2), [], @mean)];

end
```

Comment: I havent been able to try this yet but I made a few edits that may be able to help understand the question better.

Comment: @ImmortalxR My code is very easy to adapt to your new requirements. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I made a small edit to fix some typos and the use of IDs and Groups_1 that was giving my accumarray errors, feel free to correct me if I am wrong, but the newly edited code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Im actually having trouble with my code as I edited it above, where the toMultiply function seems to multiply ALL of my values in StarData(:,2) and not just the ones that should be filtered, in other words it is saying that toMultiply is as large as StarData(:,1) so it multiplies everything indiscriminantly

Comment: @ImmortalxR your edits make too many changes. The answer is enough as it stands for anyone to replicate it